# Strikethrough in MathJax

Tags: latex, mathjax, strikethrough

I am new to MathJax. My software uses MathJax and takes LaTex-like input. I am used to of using Latex commands, like [latex]\frac{2}{3}\times x^2[/latex], but I cant use any of the Latex packages to get my task done. How is strikethrough text done? In Latex it requires use of packages and there is no base command for that. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Something like https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/cancel.html ?

Comment: This actually worked, thank you.